# Set Environment Variables in UWP App not in the source code

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, uwp, environment-variables

is there a way to set environment variables in a UWP app in a launchsettings.json file or in any other way that directly in the source code?

The visual studio properties for UWP apps seem not allow to set environment variable like in oder C# projects.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Please check my reply about using environment variables in UWP Apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UWP apps are running in the sandbox, so it has limitations when accessing to the system values. You could not set System environment variable or User environment variable in UWP apps.

If you must do it in UWP apps, what you could try is to create a console app that does it. Package this exe with your UWP app and then you could use `FullTrustProcessLauncher` class to open the exe in your UWP app.

You could refer to this: [Does Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable work in UWP?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/222529/does-environment-setenvironmentvariable-work-in-uw?orderby=newest)